# Inint nuxt 3 project fails with npm package

Tags: nuxt.js, npx

> I'm trying to init a Nuxt 3 project with the command "npx nuxi@latest init proy-name".
> When I select to use the npm package, the initializing fails with the next output:

```
✔ Which package manager would you like to use? 
npm
Installing dependencies...                                                                                    2:53:16 PM
npm WARN cleanup Failed to remove some directories [
npm WARN cleanup   [
npm WARN cleanup     'C:\\vueMastery\\t-clone\\node_modules',
npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:\vueMastery\t-clone\node_modules\@nuxt\devtools'] {
npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm WARN cleanup       path: 'C:\\vueMastery\\t-clone\\node_modules\\@nuxt\\devtools'
npm WARN cleanup     }
npm WARN cleanup   ]
npm WARN cleanup ]
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\vueMastery\t-clone\node_modules\@parcel\watcher
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@10.0.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@20.11.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.12.0 found at "C:\Users\m.galvan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v20.11.0/node-v20.11.0-headers.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v20.11.0/node-v20.11.0-headers.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v20.11.0/SHASUMS256.txt
npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v20.11.0/win-x64/node.lib
npm ERR! gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v20.11.0/SHASUMS256.txt
npm ERR! gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v20.11.0/win-x64/node.lib
npm ERR! gyp info find VS using VS2022 (17.8.34511.84) found at:
npm ERR! gyp info find VS "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS run with --verbose for detailed information
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Users\m.galvan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args 'C:\\vueMastery\\t-clone\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args 'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args 'msvs',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args 'C:\\vueMastery\\t-clone\\node_modules\\@parcel\\watcher\\build\\config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args 'C:\\vueMastery\\t-clone\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args 'C:\\Users\\m.galvan\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\20.11.0\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\m.galvan\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\20.11.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\vueMastery\\t-clone\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\\\Users\\\\m.galvan\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\node-gyp\\\\Cache\\\\20.11.0\\\\<(target_arch)\\\\node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\vueMastery\\t-clone\\node_modules\\@parcel\\watcher',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args 'C:\\vueMastery\\t-clone\\node_modules\\@parcel\\watcher\\build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp: binding.gyp not found (cwd: C:\vueMastery\t-clone\node_modules\@parcel\watcher) while trying to load binding.gyp
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\vueMastery\t-clone\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:271:18)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:518:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:294:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22631
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\vueMastery\\t-clone\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\vueMastery\t-clone\node_modules\@parcel\watcher
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v20.11.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v10.0.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\m.galvan\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-01-27T19_53_17_350Z-debug-0.log
```

ERROR  Error: Command failed with exit code 1: npm install

> Could someone guide me about this issue?
> I have node 20.10.0, Windows 11.
> When i choose "yarn" package manager, all runs properly.

> Thanks in advance.